# Learning Russian through Latin: Which book should I use?

Tags: resource-request, russian

I have achieved my goal in learning Latin, which is to be able to read more or less fluently both classical and Renaissance authors.
So I think it would be fun to use Latin to learn my next language: Russian.

Do you know of any books that might be useful (grammar books, dictionaries, bilingual texts, etc.)? So far I have only found the
[Grammatica Russica](https://archive.org/details/GrammaticaRussicaHenriciWilhelmiLudolfiQuaeContinetFundamentaRussica/), but I don't know if it is reliable.

I am well aware that the Russian I will learn in this way will be old-fashioned, but I am in no hurry, so I can supplement my reading later with videos, books or even a trip to the country.

Comment: What an awesome aspiration. It makes me want to ask a similar questiona about Italian, or Ancient Greek.

Comment: Under the same link that you provided in your question you should see (if you scroll down) [Латинско-Русский Словарь](https://archive.org/details/LATINSKORUSSKIJSLOVARI.DVORENTSKIJ). As a general comment, though: the grammar books, etc do, of course, exist but naturally they are meant to help Russian speakers learn Latin, not the other way round.

Comment: As a simple demo: if you copy & paste "книги латинский и русский" into Google search and select 'Images' button you should see a bunch of pictures to get the idea of what's available...